# My IDLE does not recognize itertools.izip() as a function

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
>>> itertools.izip('ABCD', 'xy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    itertools.izip('ABCD', 'xy')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In Python 3, the builtin function `zip` behaves like `itertools.izip` did in Python 2.

Comment: Blckknght is right. If you don't know how to find python version, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/detect-python-version-at-runtime

Comment: @Blckknght Hi Blckknght,  I am using version 3.4.3.  You can see that along the top bar of the shell window too.  I am having the same problem with string.maketrans(…). see:

Comment: >>> trans = string.makestrans('ae','bx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#158>", line 1, in <module>
    trans = string.makestrans('ae','bx')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'makestrans'

Answer (score 43):

In Python 3, there is no `izip` function in the `itertools` module because the builtin `zip` function (which doesn't require any imports to access) now behaves like `itertools.izip` did in Python 2. So, to make your code work, just use `zip` instead of `itertools.izip`.

You also mentioned an issue with `string.maketrans`. That's another function that is no longer in a module in Python 3. It's now a method of the `str` class: `str.maketrans`. Note however that its behavior is a bit different than `string.maketrans` in Python 2, as the `translate` method on strings takes different arguments (a dictionary instead of a 256-character string).

It sounds like you may be following a guide written for Python 2, but using Python 3 to run your code. This can be confusing, as there were signficant changes between the major versions of the language. You should try to find a guide that targets Python 3 instead. I don't recommend using Python 2 for your coding unless you really must follow your current guide.

Comment: Thank you responding.  I was in fact following an online course video on sliderule that must have been recorded using Python 2.