# Counting strings in lists and then filtering & matching, in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, string-matching

I have a list of words, and with python3 I count the difference in letters between each combination of words (using a [clever diff_summing algorithm from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226874/2327328)):

```
import itertools

def diff_letters(a,b):
    return sum ( a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)) )

w = ['AAHS','AALS','DAHS','XYZA']

for x,y in itertools.combinations(w,2):
    if diff_letters(x,y) == 1:
        print(x,y)
```

This prints:

```
AAHS AALS
AAHS DAHS
```

**My question:** How can I count *and* record that strings 'DAHS' and 'AALS' have exactly one partner, and 'AAHS' has two partners? I'll be filtering for directional combinations where each `target_string` has *exactly one* `near_matching_word`, so my final data would (as a JSON) look like this:

```
[
 {
   "target_word": "DAHS",
   "near_matching_word": "AAHS"
 },
 {
   "target_word": "AALS",
   "near_matching_word": "AAHS"
 }
]
```

(noticing that AAHS doesn't appear as a `target_word`)

I have one version using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```
import itertools
import functools
import operator

def diff_letters(a,b):
    return sum ( a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)) )

w = ['AAHS','AALS','DAHS','XYZA']

pairs = []
for x,y in itertools.combinations(w,2):
    if diff_letters(x,y) == 1:
        #print(x,y)
        pairs.append((x,y))

full_list = functools.reduce(operator.add, pairs)
for x in full_list:
    if full_list.count(x) == 1:
        print (x)
```

which prints

```
AALS
DAHS
```

but then I would have to go back to my big list `pairs` to find the `near_matching_word`. Of course, in my final version, list `pairs` will be much larger, and the `target_word` could be either the 1st or 2nd item in the tuple (x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary instead of a list of pairs:

```
pairs = {}
for x, y in itertools.combinations(w, 2):
    if diff_letters(x, y) == 1:
        pairs.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
        pairs.setdefault(y, []).append(x)

result = [{ "target_word": key, "near_matching_word": head, } for key, (head, *tail) in pairs.items() if not tail]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'target_word': 'AALS', 'near_matching_word': 'AAHS'}, {'target_word': 'DAHS', 'near_matching_word': 'AAHS'}]
```

In the `pairs` dictionary the keys are the `target_words` and the values are the `near_matching_words`. Then use a list comprehension to filter out those that have more that 1 `near_matching_word`.

Comment: clever to use `pairs` with x and y as keys each appending y and x.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers keep all pairs even when more than one is found. Since they are not needed, that seems to waste memory. This answer only keeps at most one pair for each string.

```
import collections
import itertools

def diff_letters(a,b):
    return sum ( a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)) )

w = ['AAHS','AALS','DAHS','XYZA']

# Marker for pairs that have not been found yet.
NOT_FOUND = object()

# Collection of found pairs x => y. Each item is in one of three states:
# - y is NOT_FOUND if x has not been seen yet
# - y is a string if it is the only accepted pair for x
# - y is None if there is more than one accepted pair for x
pairs = collections.defaultdict(lambda: NOT_FOUND)

for x,y in itertools.combinations(w,2):
    if diff_letters(x,y) == 1:
        if pairs[x] is NOT_FOUND:
            pairs[x] = y
        else:
            pairs[x] = None
        if pairs[y] is NOT_FOUND:
            pairs[y] = x
        else:
            pairs[y] = None

# Remove None's and change into normal dict.
pairs = {x: y for x, y in pairs.items() if y}

for x, y in pairs.items():
    print("Target = {}, Only near matching word = {}".format(x, y))
```

Output:

```
Target = AALS, Only near matching word = AAHS
Target = DAHS, Only near matching word = AAHS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import functools
import operator


def diff_letters(a, b):
    return sum(a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)))


w = ['AAHS', 'AALS', 'DAHS', 'XYZA']

pairs = []
for x, y in itertools.combinations(w, 2):
    if diff_letters(x, y) == 1:
        pairs.append((x, y))

full_list = functools.reduce(operator.add, pairs)

result = []

for x in set(full_list):
    if full_list.count(x) == 1:
        pair = next((i for i in pairs if x in i))
        match = [i for i in pair if i != x][0]
        result.append({
            "target_word": x,
            "near_matching_word": match
        })

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'target_word': 'DAHS', 'near_matching_word': 'AAHS'}, {'target_word': 'AALS', 'near_matching_word': 'AAHS'}]
```

Comment: This might not be the most concise method, but it works. Care to explain the downvote?